# Understanding rest parameters in TypeScript 0.9.5

Tags: typescript

I'm wrtiting a small application in TypeScript. It has a module for a context menu, which has a method called `show`, declared as follows:

```
export var show = function (position: { top: number; left: number; },
    optionList: { [name: string]: (...params: any[]) => any })
```

So basically I want to show menu at certain position and pass an object which maps string to functions - these would be items in my menu and callbacks assigned to them. I want those callback to take any amount of arguments of any type - and this is how I understand the rest parameter I used here. However, when I try to invoke my function like this:

```
menu.show(
     {
         top: nativeEvent.clientY,
         left: nativeEvent.clientX + 5
     },
     {
         "Add elem...": (e: JQueryEventObject) => { }
     });
```

I get an error saying that `Call signatures of types '(e: JQueryEventObject) => void' and '(...params: any[]) => any' are incompatible` and `Call signature expects 0 or fewer parameters.`

Could anyone tell me what is going on here? Because it turns out that I completely don't understand the concept of rest parameters. Why the compiler tells me the function expects 0 parameters and how do I make it expect any amount of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since rest parameters imply all members are optional, the function you pass in must have all its members as optional `(e?: JQueryEventObject) => { }` as well e.g. :

```
var show = function (position: { top: number; left: number; },
    optionList: { [name: string]: (...params: any[]) => any }){}

show(
     {
         top: 1,
         left: 5
     },
     {
         "Add elem...": (e?: any) => { } // Notice e is optional
     });
```

Comment: Right. I looked to the spec and somehow missed that. "When comparing call or construct signatures, parameter names are ignored and rest parameters correspond to an unbounded expansion of optional parameters of the rest parameter element type." Much thanks.